# Problems connecting to existing ElasticSearch instance in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have an elasticsearch instance running locally.
I have a spring boot application.
In my application I have a service ServiceX which contains an elasticsearch repository which extends ElasticsearchRepository.
So
Service X contains
YRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository

I have an elasticsearch instance running locally.

My elastic search settings are

```
ELASTICSEARCH (ElasticsearchProperties)
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.host = localhost
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.port = 9300
```

When the application is started an elasticsearch template is created.
The client that is used is a NodeClient.
The settings for the NodeClient are

```
"http.enabled" -> "true"
"port" -> "9300"
"host" -> "localhost"
"cluster.name" -> "elasticsearch"
"node.local" -> "true"
"name" -> "Human Robot"
"path.logs" -> "C:/dev/git/xxx/logs"
```

The name of the elasticsearch (Human Robot in this case), does not match the local elasticsearch instance running (Nikki in this case).

It looks like it 
1. creates a new instance of logstash
2. creates an embedded instance of logstash.

I have searched through a lot of information but cannot find any documentation to help.

Could people please advise about what settings to use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you do not want to use the NodeClient but the TransportClient unless you want your application to become part of the cluster

I believe you have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artificatId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artificatId>
</dependency>
```

then you need to create some configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/elasticsearch.properties")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
        TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), 
                Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port"))
        );
        client.addTransportAddress(address);        
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

Also check ElasticSearch [section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-elasticsearch) of the Spring Boot guide, and especially the section about spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes if you put multiple comma seperated list of host port it will be generated a TransportClient instead, your choice

Try it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Would you believe I actually just started trying to use a configuration file before I saw your post.  I added a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig {

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
      TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
      TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
              "localhost",9300);
      client.addTransportAddress(address);
      return client;
  }
}
```

And the client is now being injected into the elasticsearch template (so don't need the elasticsearchtemplate bean).

I had an error when I tried to connect but that turned out to be due to elasticsearch 2.2.0, have tried it with elasticsearch 1.7.3 and it worked so now onto the next problem!